# Websocket with php, host always return an error

Tags: javascript, php, sockets

So, i have created a php websocket server. I'm working on WAMP.

I have launch my server with : `php -q serveur.php` and it's ok.

Now, i have a probleme with my javascript, i'm trynig to open a connection but i always have an error message with the event`socket.onerror`.

My file serveur.php is in : `c/wamp/www/tw/www/websockets/classes/serveur.php`

And i have this host: `ws://127.0.0.1:11345/tw/www/websockets/classes/serveur.php`

On my serveur.php, i have 11345 too.

So, when i do : `socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:11345/tw/www/websockets/classes/serveur.php");` i always have the event socket.onerror...

Any ideas ?

Comment: you may have a problem with your file url, what's your php configuration for your server, maybe you server.php is available from an other link like : WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:11345/serveur.php");

Comment: What do you mean by php configuration ?

Comment: I wanted to say your apache configuration

Comment: What's the error message returned in the onerror event